# Confused! Rsync command for making hard-link!

Tags: 14.04, backup, rsync

```
rsync --archive --one-file-system --hard-links --human-readable --inplace --numeric-ids --link-dest=/home/www.example.com/public_html/ /home/www.example.com/public_html/ /home/test.example.com/public_html/
```

This is the command I run.

What I got this (after delete some file from test).

```
6.3G    /home/test.example.com
576M    /home/www.example.com
```

1. Got problem If any edits done on test that affect on www? what can I do?
2. But I want the source will be the www and that will take space.
3. Is there any problem with what I currently have? Because I can delete/modify the files/folders in test site or can delete entire dir.
4. I don't care anything happen on test but care if happen on www.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got the size listing after you ran `rsync`, but in case you used `du`, recall that `du` doesn't count sizes for hard links twice. From it's man page:

```
-l, --count-links
          count sizes many times if hard linked
```

In other words, unless you pass the `-l` flag, you won't count sizes for hard linked files in both locations.

To try to address your questions:

- You're hard linking between www and test. So yes, if you make changes in test, you're going to see them reflected in www. Sounds like you don't want hard links, from your question.
- You want to save space, which is fine, but you can't both a) save space and have only one copy of the files, while b) simultaneously having the files in test and www have different content. Just not possible!

If you want to have test and www directories have the same content, but then make changes, you might just run the `rsync` command, don't use `--hard-links` and don't use `--link-dest`.